# How to select elements between two specific table rows with XPath

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I want to scrape a portion of a site that has the following HTML structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <h4 class="h4-lead text-left m-b-0">Basic Info</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Condition</strong></td>
      <td>1 (mint)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>With box</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>With papers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Gender</strong></td>
      <td>Unisex</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the text of every `td` that is the second of its type within a `tr` element between the **Condition** and **Gender** rows.

Based on the above my desired output would be:

```
['1 (mint)', 'With box', 'With papers']
```

I tried several approaches but I'm not even close to the solution.

**Please note that the number of condition rows is arbitrary, and not necessarily 3 like in this example. It can be 0, 1, 2 ... n.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//td[2][    preceding::td[.='Condition']
        and following::td[.='Gender']
       ]/text()
```

will select text nodes of all second `td` elements between `Condition` and `Gender`,

```
1 (mint)
With box
With papers
```

as requested.